# How do I turn this simple for loop into recursion

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ForloopToRecursion {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter number of sips");
 int sip = input.nextInt();
 if(sip>=10){
   int n =sip;
   for (int i = 0 ;i <sip; i++){

     System.out.println("sip of a coffee"+n);
     n--;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I need to turn this code into recursion.  The program should ask the user to enter the number of sips, and then by using recursion, print the following string each time

```
"sip of a coffee".
```

Comment: Why? Using recursion for this example does not make sense (and also would be inefficient compared to loop).

Comment: Recursion is a fundamental programming technique that should... no **MUST** be known by all who wish to become a "worthwhile programmer". The time for it's need **will** come, the purpose of "these" kind of exercises is not efficiency but understanding the concept. And that is what your teacher is trying to give you. So before you all yell "iteration is better" and "no wonder he is a teacher" keep the above said in mind. IMHO the teacher is doing exactly what is needed! @AnoudAl-Saud

Answer (score 2):

@Dima Maligin is absolutely right. This is a basic example to explain the core concept of recursion. Understanding this will help to understand more complex recursive algorithms.

To expand a little bit on the answer given by @Franscisco Hernandez:

The core concept of recursion is to reduce a problem to a smaller instance of the same problem and to contruct the result from your partial results.
To put this in programming terms: You write a function that solves a problem by calling itself.

This needs two specific parts (loosely from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)):

1. A base case at which you can stop teh recursion. I have also heard the terms floor or anchor for this. This has to be an atomic version of the problem you can easily solve.
2. A set of rules that allow you to reduce your problem into recusion steps.

Let us apply this to your example. You have got a cup of coffee which contains at least 10 sips of coffee. You have to sip them all (No pokemon reference intended here.) so you can stop if no more sips remain. This is the **base case**. Until that point is reached we sip coffee one sip at a time. In the loop each sip was done in one iteration of the loop. Here we use a recursion rule to do this. Still got sips left? Sip one, go on with one sip less. At some point (specifically after the number the user entered via the Scanner) you will run out of sips and run into the base case.

In Java code this would look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForloopToRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number of sips");
        int sip = input.nextInt();
        if(sip>=10){
            sipCoffee(sip);
        }
    }

    public static void sipCoffee(int sipsRemaining){

        // This is your recursions base
        // When you reach 0 remaining sips
        // you immediately exit the function
        // without doing anything
        // Note that the test == 0 would also suffice
        // here, but 
        if (sipsRemaining <= 0){
            return; 
        }

        // If you reached this part of the code
        // you have more than one sip remaining 
        System.out.println("Take a sip of coffee.");

        // To reduce the number of sips you call a
        // new instance of the sipCoffee function
        // with a reduced number of sipsRemaining
        // Note that you are calling the function from
        // within itself. This is the recursion step.
        sipCoffee(sipsRemaining-1);
    } // termination

}
```

Now to the funny part. A Java function terminates (i.e. is finished when) you reach the last closing curly brace (marked by ``// termination`in the code) of the function. Now notice that when you enter the function with`sipsRemaining > 0`you call another instance of`sipCoffee`. The instance from which you call has not terminated yet, because the second call has not terminated yet. This accumulates until you hit a base case.

Imagine it like this. Each of the calls to `sipCoffee` persist in memory until they can terminate. They can only terminate when they run to the end and that can only happen once the base case is reached. Then the focus jumps back to `sipCoffee(1)` which can terminate then `sipCoffee(2)` can terminate etc.

```
...
sipCoffee(5)
|
| sipCoffee(4)
| |
| | sipCoffee(3)
| | |
| | | sipCoffee(2)
| | | |
| | | | sipCoffee(1)
| | | | |
| | | | | sipCoffee(0)
| | | | | |
| | | | | * terminates
| | | | |
| | | | * terminates
| | | |
| | | * terminates
| | |
| | * terminates
| |
| * terminates
|
* terminates
```

I hope this helps. When keeping in mind that this is a typical programming 101 assignment many more tasks involving recursion are to come. You want to understand this before you reach fancy stuff like quick sort. Have fun :)

Comment: (+1) Although I do not think the OP deserved it, the question was a bit "do it for me". I tend to not invest my time on questions that the asker did not take the time to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
package a;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForloopToRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number of sips");
        int sip = input.nextInt();

        if (sip >= 10) {
            int n = sip;
            recursion(n);
            /*for (int i = 0; i < sip; i++) {

                System.out.println("sip of a coffee" + n);
                n--;
            }*/
        }
    }

    private static void recursion(int sip) {

        if (sip == 0) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("sip of a coffee" + sip);

        recursion(sip-1);
    }
}
```